High GPU Usage in Unity Editor with 4K Monitor and HDRP in Empty Scene
I recently upgraded my monitor, switching from 2K 144Hz to 4K 60Hz, and I didn’t expect much of a performance difference — and for most applications, there isn’t. However, my Unity Editor has gone haywire with the new monitor. I understand that the Editor is demanding because it renders everything at the monitor's native resolution, but having an empty HDRP scene open on the 4K monitor causes my GPU usage to spike to 70-90%.
On my previous 2K monitor, I could open large scenes and still have a quiet PC, with minimal GPU load. I also have two Full HD monitors beside my 4K display, and when I move the Unity Editor window to one of those, it behaves normally and my PC remains silent, even with large scenes full of lights and objects — GPU usage hovers around 20-35%. It doesn’t seem right that an empty scene would cause up to 90% usage on an RTX 3060 Ti.
Any tips or insights would be greatly appreciated!
I’ve tried disabling HDR (which is new on the 4K monitor), turned off G-Sync in the NVIDIA settings, and even played around with V-Sync and the Editor’s settings. I'm also using HDRP’s "Performant" settings and Unity 6’s new instanced renderer, though I’m not sure if that affects the Editor’s rendering. I’ve disabled post-processing effects, anti-aliasing, and even tried DLSS, but nothing seems to change the GPU load.
Edit:
Weeks Later,
I've tested an empty project by importing the HDRP Fountain Bleu Demo. In the demo scene, which has a lot of detail, I'm only seeing around 5% GPU usage in the Editor (with Post Processing and Always Refresh turned off). However, in my own project—even with an empty scene and no objects—I can't reach the same level of GPU usage or temperature as the Fountain Bleu demo even close.
What could be causing this low GPU utilization in my project, even when there are no objects in the scene but having no troubles in another project with many objects?

well, your card should be doing OK, but are now rendering 4x the size of before, but does the profiler not help?

do you get the same effect if you set the resolution lower? (ideally to 2K) .. that said, SO isntt a great place for this sort of Question, and you're probably better off with the superuser SE instead https://superuser.com/

Unfortunately  I never used the profiler before so I dont know how to test the Editor. But I tried Unity with 2k and the results are much better. I still got a feeling the 144hz 2k went better with my old Monitor as the 2k 60hz on this one but I cant test it for sure because I dont have the monitor anymore.
It's still a mystery to me why I m able to have a huge scene open with 2k but not an empty scene without 1 object on 4k.

Well, 4k has pixel amount x4 comparing to 2k. It is like jump from 1280 x 1024 to 2k. So if 2k taking 20-35% of gpu, 4k would take 80-140%.
But I have kinda same problem with games, that my 3060TI going to jet fighter mode, when playing. So I used MSI afterburner and limited temp to 80 C and power consumprion to 80%, also played with fan curve. And now it is very silent. Of couse it will "eat" part of performance, but in Unity you probably don't need all of it.

Its still not perfect but after deleting my 65 Gb Library folder and disabling HDR in Windows not Unity, I get around 20% in the empty scene and 40% in my Testing Scene which seems reasonable for the 4k.
I think there is still some improvement or another issue but at least I m able to work on my 4k Screen now.
